# Can we use different datatypes in a linkedlist?

Tags: types, linked-list

Generally in a linked list we store elements of similar datatypes.

Example:
1-->2-->3-->4
(or)
a-->b-->c-->d

My doubt is..can we store the elements in a linked list like

1-->a-->2-->e-->9

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Sure you can. Just depends on your implementation.

Comment: Sure (adapted as required for a particular language). There is no fundamental property of a linked list ADT that prevents this. The values of each node are *independent* of the 'linking' itself.